# Using prepped data after validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have this validation rule in CodeIgniter:

```
'bookForm' => array(
     array(
         'field'   => 'title', 
         'label'   => 'Title', 
         'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[10]'
     )
)
```

I was wondering if I'm doing this right or wrong, because when I enter a space followed by a string which is 10 in length, it's supposed to be trim and evaluate if it's a string 10 in length - which it does.

However, when I try to get the data after it passes validation, the string still has the space in front. Is this the right behavior of CI? I mean i just trimmed data in validation, do I have to trim those once more for storage? If I actually needed the string to be MD5'ed, I would do MD5 on it again after? (Talk about redundancy)

Comment: I edited my answer. Don't know why I thought that the normal behavior would be repeating the operation after the validation. If this still happening to you in 2.2.0 it may be a bug. The note just say to use your prepping functions in the final of the validation, and not to duplicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Looking in the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) we can see that indeed the content must be trimmed after the validation.</strike>

> Note: You will generally want to use the prepping functions after the validation rules so if there is an error, the original data will be shown in the form.

**EDIT**

A quick test in CI 2.2.0 with the `md5` function shows that the POST variable is changed after the validation, avoiding redundancy.

Comment: so does that mean I have to do a trim in the validation rule AND do it again after it passes? (Actually i was confused by that line as it had no example of what it meant)

Comment: I arrived here by a Google result and I would like to clarify that, as for 2014, this is no longer true. Using a prepping function will actually modify the POST element with the changes, so if you added trim on 'name', $this->input->post('name') will return the trimmed string. This is the expected behavior (I don't think, for example, it is useful to use xss_clean or md5 for validation purposes)

Comment: @DanielCastro You're correct, I don't know why I thought in that way before.